# ReactJS: First useEffect doesn't update state before the second is triggered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a Chat component which uses API to populate the `messages` state, also there are different areas that have different chats which I pass as props to the component.

In this component I have 3 `useEffects` but I am interested in two of them which don't work properly. In the first useEffect I have some code that basically resets the `messages` state on area change to `undefined`. I need to do this to be able to distinguish between the API not being called yet where I display a loading component `<Spinner />` or if the API has been called and it has retrieved an empty array to show the `<NoData>` component.

The problem that I have is that when I change areas the `useEffects` get triggered as they should but the first `useEffect` doesn't update the `messages` state to undefined before the second `useEffect` is called. And after a rerender because of history push the messages come as undefined but then the second `useEffect` doesn't get triggered anymore. I don't get why the state is not being updated in the first `useEffect` before the second. Also the weird thing is this used to work for me before now it doesn't. I changed some stuff up without pushing to git and now I am puzzeled. Code below:

```
export default function ChatPage({ history, match, area, ...props }) {
  const [templates, setTemplates] = useState([]);
  const [advisors, setAdvisors] = useState([]);
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState(undefined);
  const [conversation, setConversation] = useState([]);
  const [chatToLoad, setChatToLoad] = useState(false);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [linkOrigin, setLinkOrigin] = useState("");
  const [headerText, setHeaderText] = useState("");

  // useEffect used to reset messages and conversation state
  // triggered on area change(messages and conversation reset)
  // and customer ID change(conversation reset).
  // Required to distinguish between API call not being made yet
  // and API returning no data.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (match.params.id) {
      setLinkOrigin(match.params.id);
    }

    if (messages) {
      if (match.params.id && messages.length !== 0) {
        let matches = messages.filter(
          (message) => message.ORIGINATOR === match.params.id
        );

        if (matches.length !== 0 && match.params.id === linkOrigin) {
          setMessages(undefined);
          history.push("/chats/" + match.params.area);
        }
      }
    }

    setConversation([]);
  }, [area, match.params.id]);

  // API calls
  useEffect(() => {
    if (templates.length === 0) {
      api.getTemplates().then((templates) => {
        setTemplates(templates);
      });
    }

    if (advisors.length === 0) {
      api.getAgents().then((advisors) => {
        setAdvisors(advisors);
      });
    }

    if (!messages || messages.length === 0) {
      chooseQueue(match.params.area).then((queuesData) => {
        let queues = queuesData.data.map((message) => ({
          DATE_SORT: message.DATE_RECIEVED,
          UNIQUEID: message.UNIQUEID,
          ORIGINATOR: message.ORIGINATOR,
          MESSAGE: message.MESSAGE,
          MSG_TYPE: "SMS_OUTBOUND",
          ASSIGNED_TO: message.ASSIGNED_TO || null,
        }));

        setMessages(orderMessagesByDate(queues));
        setChatToLoad(queues[0]);
      });
    }
  }, [area]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (messages) {
      if (messages.length) {
        let loadId = match.params.id ? match.params.id : messages[0].ORIGINATOR;

        const params = {
          MobileNumber: loadId,
        };
        messagingApi.conversationHistory(params).then((conversationData) => {
          setConversation(
            conversationData.data.map((message) => ({
              DATE_SORT: message.DATE_SORT,
              UNIQUEID: message.UNIQUEID,
              ORIGINATOR: message.ORIGINATOR,
              MESSAGE: message.MESSAGE,
              MSG_TYPE: message.MSG_TYPE2.replace("MobileOriginated", "SMS"),
              ASSIGNED_TO: message.ASSIGNED_TO || null,
            }))
          );
        });

        setChatToLoad(
          messages.find((message) => message.ORIGINATOR === loadId)
        );
        history.push("/chats/" + match.params.area + "/" + loadId);
      }
    }
  }, [messages]);

  function chooseQueue(queueType) {
    switch (queueType) {
      case "myqueue":
        setHeaderText("My chats");
        return queuesApi.getMyActiveQueues(area);
      case "mycompleted":
        setHeaderText("My completed chats");
        return queuesApi.getMyCompletedQueues();
      case "queues":
        setHeaderText("Chats");
        return queuesApi.getQueues(area);
      case "completed":
        setHeaderText("Completed chats");
        return queuesApi.getCompletedQueues();
      default:
        setHeaderText("My chats");
        return queuesApi.getQueues(area);
    }
  }

  function classifyMessage(message) {
    return message.MSG_TYPE.includes("OUTBOUND") ||
      message.MSG_TYPE.includes("FAULT_TEST")
      ? "outbound"
      : "inbound";
  }

  async function submitMessage(message) {
    var params = {
      number: message.ORIGINATOR,
      message: message.MESSAGE,
      smssize: message.MESSAGE.length
    };
    await messagingApi.replyToCustomer(params).then((res) => {
      if (res.data[0].RVALUE === "200") {
        let extendedMsg = [...messages, message];
        let extendedConversation = [...conversation, message];
        setConversation([...extendedConversation]);
        setMessages(orderMessagesByDate([...extendedMsg]));
      }
    });
  }

  function orderMessagesByDate(list) {
    return list.sort(function(x, y) {
      return new Date(y.DATE_SORT) - new Date(x.DATE_SORT);
    });
  }

  const modalHandler = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  let chatConfig = {
    channelSwitch: true,
    channels: channels,
    templateModal: true,
    templates: templates,
    advisorModal: true,
    advisors: advisors,
  };

  const onActiveChatChange = (message) => {
    history.push("/chats/" + match.params.area + "/" + message.ORIGINATOR);

    const params = {
      MobileNumber: message.ORIGINATOR,
    };
    messagingApi.conversationHistory(params).then((conversationData) => {
      setConversation(
        conversationData.data.map((message) => ({
          DATE_SORT: message.DATE_SORT,
          UNIQUEID: message.UNIQUEID,
          ORIGINATOR: message.ORIGINATOR,
          MESSAGE: message.MESSAGE,
          ASSIGNED_TO: message.ASSIGNED_TO || null,
        }))
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <div data-test="component">
      <BodyHeader
        text={headerText}
        children={
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            icon="plus-square"
            aria-hidden="true"
            size="2x"
            onClick={modalHandler}
          />
        }
      />
      {messages && chatToLoad ? (
        <>
          <ChatWindow
            messages={messages}
            conversation={conversation}
            chatToLoad={chatToLoad}
            onActiveChatChange={onActiveChatChange}
            classifyMessage={classifyMessage}
            submitMessage={submitMessage}
            config={chatConfig}
          />
          <SendMessageModal isOpen={isOpen} toggle={modalHandler} />
        </>
      ) : !messages ? (
        <Spinner />
      ) : (
        <NoDataHeader>There are no chats in this area</NoDataHeader>
      )}
          
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get what you want this way. A state change applied in a useEffect won't have effect until the next rendering cycle, the following callbacks will still see the current const value.
If you want to change the value in the current rendering cycle the only option you have is to relax your const into let and set the variables yourself.

After all: you were expecting a const to change isn't it? ;)

Comment: Pretty much what I needed to get what happened. Was really confused how I made it work previously but it's all good now.